# Key error: html 5 form submission using pyramid

Tags: python, html, unicode, pyramid

I have a very simple pyramid/pylons web app with only one page (home) detailed on the home.pt template shown below:

```
 <form action="/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="left" id="choice1"/>
<label for="choice1">Choice1</label>
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="right" id="choice2"/>
<label for="choice2">Choice2</label></div>
<p>Form Controls</p>
<input type="submit" name='form.submitted' value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the view config associated with it:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/home.pt')
def home(request):
    choices=random.sample(ranges.items(),2)
    choice1=choices[0]
    choice2=choices[1]
    output=request.GET["myradio"]
    return {'choice1':choice1,'choice2':choice2, 'output':output, "myradio":myradio}
```

This gives me a simple `KeyError: 'myradio'`.

edit: If I need any more detail, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: read up on http form submission. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and the value you are looking for will be in the dict at request.POST in your view function.

Comment: but so it would be request.POST[?]. Would it be request.POST[choice1,choice2]? Would it output a boolean, a variable, a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is what I did to fix it.

Instead of

```
output=request.GET["myradio"]
```

I now have

```
post_data=request.POST
output=post_data.get('myradio')
```

of course I also had to change the form to a get form (updated above in the question)

This gives an output of "left" if I select the left button and submit and an output of "right" if I select the right button and submit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do `request.POST.get('myradio')`, and that would return you 'left' or 'right' depending on which is selected.

Comment: well when I do that, I get TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. When I remove the .get (see updated code above), I get KeyError: "No key 'myradio': Not a form request".